# Output by average per day (Mon, Tue, etc.)

Tags: python, pandas, average

Currently I have a csv file containing thousands of rows. Each row shows a date and time but not in ascending order. How do I count the number of events/occurrence according to the days (Mon, Tue, Wed, etc.)? In addition, it should be the average number of occurrences per day. For example the average number of occurrences every Mon is 712, every Tue is 853, etc.

So far I managed to add in a column for the respective day using the line

```
df['DAY'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE']).dt.day_name()
```

[First 10 rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bQCna.png)
but I do not know how to proceed to produce an output containing the average number of occurrences per day (Mon, Tue, etc.) using Python.

The output should show:
[average for Mon   average for Tue   average for Wed   etc.]

Comment: You need to show us a sample input dataframe and the expected output for the example. Please include code to instantiate the dataframe as well (not just its string representation).

Comment: I have edited to show more information.

Comment: Sadly your edit does not cover the hints I gave you for writing a good question.

Comment: I have only started learning python hence I may not be able to fully understand what exactly is needed.

Comment: 1. A sample dataframe in the question itself. 2. Code to instantiate the dataframe (not essential, but very much appreciated). 3. A dataframe with the result you want for the given sample. -- All of this as text, not as pictures.

Answer (score 0):

To return the day names of the DateTimeIndex with specified locale Monday-Sunday

```
df['DAY'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE']).dt.day_name()
```

follow by creating a column to denote the instances of occurrence if you don't already have a column to aggregate:

```
#I'm assuming each day refers to a unique "instance" or occurrence 
#but this does not have to follow if you already have a column to count/aggregate
df['OCCURENCE'] = 1
```

To return, the average number of occurrences for a given day simply use a groupby statement and specify the group you would like to average:

```
group_df = df.groupby('DAY')['OCCURENCE'].mean()
```

To satisfy the weird format requirement of having everything in a list

```
output_list = []
for day in group_df.index:
    avg = group_df.loc[day][0]
    str_format = 'average for {d}:{v}'.foramt(d=day, v=avg) 
    output_list.append(str_format)

new_list = ' '.join(output_list)
```

Comment: I have edited the question to show more information. I need the output to show in a single line like this : [average for Mon average for Tue average for Wed etc.]

Comment: You can simply iterate over the df I created "group_df" to append to a list. I'll add that as an extension of my code.